# Extened class not able to get data from parent class

Tags: php, class, subclass

I am trying to use a display function in my extened class that first fetches a display function in the parent class. It however does not display the variable in the echo statement. The gameType (In this case "One-day") does not display.

```
<?php
class Cricket
{
    protected $gameType;

    function __construct($gameType)
    {
        $this->gameType=$gameType;
    }

    function display()
    {
        echo 'The cricket match is a ' . $this->gameType . " match";
    }
}

class Bowler extends Cricket
{
    public $type;
    public $number;

    function __construct($type,$number)
    {
        $this->type=$type;
        $this->number=$number;

        parent::__construct($this->gameType);
    }

    function display()
    {
        parent:: display();
        echo " with " . $this->number . " " . $this->type . " bowler";
    }
}   

$one = new Cricket("day-night");
$one->display();

echo'<br>';

$two  = new Cricket("day-night");
$two = new Bowler("left-hand","2");
$two->display();
?>
```

Comment: It is useless to pass `$this->gameType` to parent, parent class already has access to it.

Comment: No idea where `One-day` is supposed to come from, but it looks like you want to pass `$this->type` to the constructor of the parent instead of `$this->gameType`.

Comment: `$two  = new Cricket()` and `$two = new Bowler()` ??? `$two` can only be ONE thing at a time. [There can be only one :)]

Comment: Ok is there can only be one(which I get) how can I get the last display to show the following but still using the partent display function.  "The cricket match is a  one-day match with 2 left hand bowlers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of instantiating your Bowler class will in fact, as is implied by calling the parents constructor `parent::__construct();`, create a brand new Cricket class as well as the Bowler class.

So attempting to access a property of this newly created Cricket class makes no sense.

So when you instantiate the `Bowler` class you will also have to pass any data that the Cricket class requires for it's successful construction.

So for example

```
<?php
class Cricket
{
    protected $gameType;

    function __construct($gameType)
    {
        $this->gameType=$gameType;
    }

    function display()
    {
        echo 'The cricket match is a ' . $this->gameType . " match";
    }
}

class Bowler extends Cricket
{
    public $type;
    public $number;

    function __construct($gameType, $type, $number)
    {
        $this->type=$type;
        $this->number=$number;

        parent::__construct($gameType);
    }

    function display()
    {
        parent:: display();
        echo " with " . $this->number . " " . $this->type . " bowler";
    }
}   

$two = new Bowler('day-night', "left-hand","2");
$two->display();
```